# Unity 5 GetPixels from a Texture and then SetPixels on another Texture, this make a mess

Tags: c#, webcam, unity-game-engine

I'm trying to get from a photo, taken with WebCamTexture, the face of the player and then apply it to a texture of a 3D model so that the face of the player is going to replace the one of the model. I have the photo and I have the texture ready to mix up but I tried it in different ways, with two cycles and with a getPixels to area, but nothing, only appears a messed up square on the area I need to edit (the right area). The image below demonstrates what I need:

[image: The Result]

EDIT:
This is what I tried:

```
    //path of the photo taken
_SavePath = Application.dataPath+"/Snap";
//The texture of the photo taken from WebCamTexture (my webcam output is 800x600)
Texture2D snap = new Texture2D(wct.width, wct.height);
//The texture of the 3D model (800x800 px) that I need to edit to apply a section of the photo taken (snap texture)
Texture2D texFace = new Texture2D(OrigText.width, OrigText.height);
//set pixels of the photo
snap.SetPixels(wct.GetPixels());
snap.Apply();
//This divides the image into logic squares so find the points from where to start the loop to get the section of the photo (based on the webcam output resolution) 
int sc_ux = snap.width / 8;
int sc_uy = snap.height / 6;
//same here for the final 3D Model texture
int te_ux = texFace.width / 6;
int te_uy = texFace.height / 6;
//Getting the points 
int x1 = sc_ux * 3;
int y1 = sc_uy * 2;
int x2 = sc_ux * 5;
int y2 = sc_uy * 5;
int x3 = te_ux * 2;
int y3 = te_uy * 1;
int x4 = te_ux * 4;
int y4 = te_uy * 4;

int xx = x1;
int yy = y1;
//same of SetPixels function, I've tried with a loop too. Here I create a copy of the original texture (OrigText) to texFace.
for (int y = 0; y < OrigText.height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < OrigText.width; x++) {
        texFace.SetPixel (x, y, OrigText.GetPixel (x, y));
    }
}
texFace.Apply ();
//Then I loop starti from the area that I need to change with the pixels of the area I need from snap texture (photo taken from webcam)
for (int y = y3; y <= y4; y++) {
    for (int x = x3; x <= x4; x++) {
        Color getcolor = snap.GetPixel(xx, yy);
        texFace.SetPixel (x, y, getcolor);
        xx += 1;
    }
    yy += 1;
}
//apply
texFace.Apply();
```

And this is what I get from that:

[image: Not what I want]

Can someone help me?

Comment: shouldn't you reset `xx` sometime: `yy += 1; xx = x1;`

Comment: You're right, I'll try it.

Comment: As a side note, you should try to use Set/GetPixels32, those are more memory friendly.

Comment: @TaW you're right, now the error was the missing x reset, now it works. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you to look into using a RenderTexture instead of copying the pixels in from an array, that way you have much more control over what you are doing. You can use Unity UI and render two textures to a render texture target one with the head texture and then the camera feed of the taken photo onto a quad ontop of the texture, when these things have been rendered I would get the pixels of the render texture and encode that as a PNG using renderTextureTarget.EncodeToPNG() and then save to the disk and load onto the 3d model later :-)

Answer (score 0):

From Unity 5.4b-5 you can use [Graphics.CopyTexture](http://docs.unity3d.com/540/Documentation/ScriptReference/Graphics.CopyTexture.html) to copy the entire or partial content of a texture onto another texture.